# Vaadin attach class to Page?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, vaadin

How can I mock 'Page' and set the class's page to my mock? (Is that even possible?)

```
public class Example extends CssLayout(){

    public void notification(){
        Notification notif = new Notification("Title", "Message", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
        notif.setStyleName("Warning");
        notif.setPosition(Position.TOP_CENTER);
        notif.setDelayMsec(10000);
        notif.show(Page.getCurrent());

    }
}
```

What I want to do :

```
Example example = new Example();
Page p = mock(Page.class);
example.setPage(p)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin UI class creates and owns Page instance. You can set your mock with reflection but be careful because you might end up implementing a lot of Page class functionality in your mock, depending how much your application uses Page or framework in general.

If you want to mock out Vaadin for unit tests, it might be good a good idea to create a utility class that mocks and sets up these classes: UI, VaadinService, VaadinSession, VaadinRequest and Navigator.

Here's a Mockito unit test that mocks Page class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HelloUiTest {
    private HelloUi ui;

    @Mock
    private Page page;

    @Mock
    private VaadinRequest req;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        initUi();
        mockPage();
    }

    private void initUi() {
        ui = new HelloUi();
        ui.init(req);
        CurrentInstance.setInheritable(UI.class, ui);
    }

    private void mockPage() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field pageField = UI.class.getDeclaredField("page");
        pageField.setAccessible(true);
        pageField.set(ui, page);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotification() {
        ui.getButton().click();

        verify(page).getLocation();
    }
}
```

Functionality that this tests is this click listener:

```
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
        Notification.show("You are at: " + Page.getCurrent().getLocation());
    }
});
```